# Copy String to different Object

Tags: java

I have a scenario where I need to copy a string into a different object.

For example:

```
MyObjectData tObj = convertJSONToStr (String jsonBody);
```

But this method `convertJSONToStr()` returns String. I need to pass that object below.

```
MyExecuteClass.send (tObj);
```

In this case, how to convert or copy String to MyObjectData?

I tried like `MyObjectData tObj = (MyObjectData) convertJSONToStr (String jsonBody);` but that is not copying.

Is this correct way to do?
How can I copy that string data into `MyObjectData`? Or Please give some idea how to approach it solve? Please let me know if more details required.

Comment: Normally, you *don't need to copy Strings* in Java.  That's why methods and classes normally don't do that.  But if you must, I think `new String( String )` always makes a new string.

Comment: Are you asking how to parse JSON in Java? If so, I suggest you google for "How to parse JSON in Java".

Comment: Already JSON parsed and return the data as String in method convertJSONToStr.

Comment: If you want to construct MyObjectData from a String, you need to write such a constructor or static conversion method. Since we don't know what your JSON or MyObjectData look like, we can't give any advice beyond "copy JSON fields into object fields.

Comment: Ok Robert. I got some idea based on your suggestion. JSON is converted to String in convertJSONToStr, so there is no longer JSON after convertJSONToStr. I'll share more code shortly.

Answer (score 1):

MyObjectData can have member variable as the String. Then you can get the String and set it through setter or using a constructor.

```
public class MyObjectData {

private String jsonString;

public MyObjectData(String jsonString) {
  this.jsonString = jsonString;
}

public String getJsonString() {
return jsonString;
}

public void setJsonString(String jsonString) {
  this.jsonString = jsonString;
}

}
```

You can then instantiate the object with the returned string
    new MyObjectData(jsonString);

```
MyObjectData myObjectData = new 
.setJsonString();
myObjectData.setJsonString(jsonString);
```

Inside MyExecuteClass, you can get the string through getter getJsonString().

Comment: This is Good. But, I want to copy that String Obj coming out of convertJSONToStr directly to MyObjectData. Something like Obejectcopy/Memcopy. That means, As "Robert" mentioned MyObjectData should have same structure to accept String Obj . Thank you for your answer too.